# How to extract the value of the datetime attribute in a time tag using xpath or css selector in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract the date of the review from the datetime attribute of the  tag in an HTML document.

I've been attempting to use different variations of xpath and css selector to achieve this but they return empty strings.

the HTML tag looks like below:

```html
<time class="review-date--tooltip-target" datetime="2013-10-09T13:47:14.000Z" title= "Wednesday, 9 October 2013, 13:47:14">9 Oct 2013</time>
```

and, here's my xpath and css selector:

`xpath('//time[@class="review-date--tooltip-target"]')`

`css('time.review-date--tooltip-target')`

two outcomes will help me:

```
1- extract the value of the `datetime` attribute

2- extract the text `9 Oct 2013` within the time tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Scrapy you need:

```
datetime = response.xpath('//time[@class="review-date--tooltip-target"]/@datetime').extract_first()
time = response.xpath('//time[@class="review-date--tooltip-target"]/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following code this should return your expected value.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//time[@class='review-date--tooltip-target']").text)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//time[@class='review-date--tooltip-target']").get_attribute("datetime"))
```

Output:

```
9 Oct 2013
2013-10-09T13:47:14.000Z
```

---

Or You can induce `WebdriverWait`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//time[@class='review-date--tooltip-target']")))
print(element.text)
print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
print(element.get_attribute("datetime"))
```

---

OR You can try python `Beautifulsoup` for **scraping**.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("URL")
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('time').text)
print(soup.find('time')['datetime'])
```

---

By Using scrapy selector try that.get() will return the first match if there several match try use getall()

---

```
Datetimeval = response.css('time::attr(datetime)').get()
Textval = response.css('time::text').get()
```

Comment: thanks for responding so swiftly! I should have probably mentioned that I'm using  `scrapy`'s `Selector` object. It still doesn't return the date. Out of interest, why do you think the same `xpath` pattern doesn't work using selector instead of selenium?

Comment: @LalehH : Ok I thought you want to extract values using Python selenium.

Answer (score 2):

To get the datetime attribute, the xpath expression

```
//time[@class="review-date--tooltip-target"]/@datetime
```

outputs

```
2013-10-09T13:47:14.000Z
```

To get the date text within the time tag, the xpath expression

```
//time[@class="review-date--tooltip-target"]/text()
```

outputs

```
9 Oct 2013
```